# Proof that changing a finite number of terms in a series does not change where or not it converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I want to prove the following theorem:

> Changing a finite number of terms in a series does not change whether or not it converges, although it may change the value of its sum if it does converge

I don't know how to begin as I am not sure how to translate that statement into symbols. Furthermore, I am not sure what "Changing a finite number of terms" means. Does it mean changing the value of a particular term or omitting it entirely or something else?

Please advise.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's criterion for the convergence of a series?

Comment: It seems to me from the statement that "changing" means actually replacing a finite amount of terms of the series with different numbers. It is known that if you separate the series into a finite number of terms and the remaining (an infinite sum) convergence is not affected, this is a classical result. You may want to use it to prove what you want, which now becomes an easy corollary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \to x$. This means for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, then $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$.

Now suppose $x'_n$ is a sequence such that for $n \ge M$, then $x'_n = x_n$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N$ that 'works' for the original sequence $x_n$. Now take $N'= \max(N,M)$. Then if $n \ge N'$, we have $|x'_n -x| < \epsilon$. Hence $x'_n \to x$.

Now consider a convergent series $\sum_n x_n$. If we let $s_n = x_1+...+x_n$, then we have $s_n \to s$.

Now consider the series $\sum_n x'_n$, where for $n \ge M$, then $x'_n = x_n$.
Let  $s'_n = x'_1+...+x'_n$. Note that for $n \ge M$, we have $s'_n -s'_{M-1} = x'_M+...x'_n = x_M+...x_n$, and so $s'_n -s'_{M-1} = s_n -s_{M-1} \to s -s_{M-1}$.

Hence $s'_n \to (s -s_{M-1}+s'_{M-1})$.

Comment: I don't understand why is it that even when we showed that the sequence for both $x_n$ and $x'_n$ converges to $x$, the sum of their series is different. Also, based on my understanding of the proof, it seems that the sum of $x'_n$ will always be different from $x_n$ since we need to add $s'_{M-1}$. Is this right?

Comment: @mauna: If you start summing the two sequence at $n=M$ (the point at which the two sequences are equal) then the two sums will obviously converge to the same number since they are the same. So the total sums only differ by $(x_1+...+x_{M-1})-(x'_1+...+x'_{M-1})$.

Comment: Okay, got it. So the statement says "it may change the value of its sum if it does converge". To me that means there are occasions where the sum would be the same.But if we always sum from the first term of each sequence, then their respective sums would always differ, right? So, instead of saying "may change", why don't we say "will change"? (Clearly, i'm assuming the statement is implicitly saying sum from the first term. Is this wrong?)

Comment: No, 'may' is the correct term. The series $0,0,....$ and $-1,1,0,0,...$ have a finite number of different terms but they converge to the same sum.

Answer (score 3):

Cauchy's criterion for convergence (assuming we're dealing with $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$, technically a complete space in complete generality) says that a series $\{s_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ with $s_n = a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_k$ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N > 0$ so that for all $m > n \geq N$, we have
$$
\left| s_m - s_n \right| = \left| \sum_{k = 0}^m a_k - \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \right| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k\right| < \epsilon.
$$
The key thing to realize is the "there is an $N > 0$ so that for all $m > n \geq N$." This is basically saying that it doesn't matter what happens for a finite number of terms before we get to a certain cutoff point.

So, suppose we change a finite number of terms in a series and say that $K$ is the largest $a_K$ that we change in the series. If we take $N_0 > \max(K,N)$, where $N$ is given as in the equivalence above (since we know the original series converges), we still obtain
$$
\left| \sum_{k = 0}^m a_k - \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \right| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k\right| < \epsilon.
$$
for all $m > n \geq N_0$. Therefore, the convergence of the series is not affected in the sense that one converges if and only if the other does also. However, they may in fact converge to different limits because the Cauchy Criterion does not give any information about the limit itself.